# What´s the difference in between id and itemID in Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working in a project based in Sencha 2.3.1 but It´s not working the button with ItemID but it´s correctly working with the ID property.. What is the mistake??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

id : The id of a component translates to an html id attribute. As for html, the id must be unique in the document or application.

itemId : The itemId is a reference internal to ExtJs. It doesn't need to be globally unique, but it must be unique among the child components from the parent where you want to use the reference. No two sibling components can have the same itemId.

Comment: OK! I understand.. my mistake was the best practice to identify Dom´s components, but I think with ID is enough.

Thanks Lorenz!

Comment: Attention component queries and dom element queries are two separate concepts in ExtJs.